# Kong GCP setup initiating weekly migrations which is breaking the datastore and admin access

Tags: kong

I have a Kong setup from the marketplace on GCP. After having set up the services and route, in the container logs, there is a migration update that has been initiated automatically which ended up flushing my datastore and showing me an error {"message":"An unexpected error occurred"} while accessing the admin panel.

How can I disable the auto migrations/ how to persist the datastore and access to the admin panel?

[Logs from gke workload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYPVc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to run the migrations in their own ephemeral container, but disable is possible.

From Kong github:

docker-compose v2: https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml

docker-compose v3: https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/blob/master/swarm/docker-compose.yml

There are migration services

```
services:

  kong-migrations:
image: "${KONG_DOCKER_TAG:-kong:latest}"
command: kong migrations bootstrap

 kong-migrations-up:
image: "${KONG_DOCKER_TAG:-kong:latest}"
command: kong migrations up && kong migrations finish
```

I deployed a Kong from GCP MarketPlace , in the YAML file for the kong deployments it includes a container to run the migrations (as my previous suggestion)

```
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - until kong migrations up; do echo waiting for database and migrations; sleep
      2; done;
```

You can edit your deployment to remove these entries

Comment: Great! Thanks. It seems to resolve my issue for now. However, I understand from Kong that the GCP version is soon going to be deprecated.